# Timestamp comparison is failing in spark SQL in databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks-sql

I was executing below simple Spark-SQL code azure databricks.

```scala
val df2=spark.sql(
          s"""
select 
mbrgm.mbrgm_id as case_id,
      case
        when mbr_hist.meck is not null
          and mbr_hist.efdt is not null
          and mbr_hist.efdt <= mbr_pgm.credttm
          and (
            mbr_hist.exp_dt is null
             or mbr_hist.exp_dt > mbrgm.creat_dttm
          ) then mbr_hist.meck
        else mbrgm.facmbid
      end as mb_fid,
     .....
     from 
     tempview1 mbrgm 
     left join left outer join tempview2 mbr_hist on (mbrgm.mrid = mbr_hist.mrid
        and mbr_hist.efdt <= mbrgm.credttm
        and mbr_hist.exdt > mbrgm.credttm
```

Every time I execute I get else condition value for mb_fid field i.e, mbrgm.facmbid. I have checked My data and compared with logic. As per logic it should go for then condition. I think while comparing `mbr_hist.efdt <= mbr_pgm.credttm` it is always not true.

I am having **mbr_hist.efdt as a String type ex: 2017-07-22 21:58:46** and **mbr_pgm.credttm as a timestamp ex:2011-08-13T11:00:00.910+0000**. Is it like because of different in length of values ,my comparison is failing. What I can use to compare correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks can't directly compare the string with timestamp. You need to convert your string into the timestamp. By default, `cast` works only with strings in the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so you need to use the [to_timestamp](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_timestamp.html) function with explicit [date/time pattern](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) to do the conversion.

like

```sql
select to_timestamp(mbr_hist.efdt, 'pattern') as efdt ...
```